# After Unistalling Epson Easy Photo Printer, there is a leftover white line from the menu bar

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, printer

I installed Epson Easy Photo Print without knowing it was bloatware that installs this annoying toolbar into Windows 10's Explorer. It's hideous. Not only that, it forces the Menu Bar to display at all times, with no option to disable it. I could unistall it with Revo Unistaller, however, after uninstalling it, there is some sort of toolbar leftover that wasn´t there before I installed the "utility" in the first place.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBpwd.png)

Comment: Maybe try tools like Malwarebytes or Spybot.

Comment: Uninstall the Epson software in Programs a Features, then remove the driver(s) in Devices and Printers, Driver Tab. Close out, restart and see if it is gone.

Comment: The software is already uninstalled.  So have you tried to reboot?  You could also just close and restart File Explorer.

Comment: Yup, I removed everything, even the string in the registry, rebooted, nothings seems to work